# Where did the command-backtick keyboard shortcut go in 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager

With every Mac OS X I've ever used, hitting command-backtick (`) cycled to the next window.  I just installed Mac OS X 10.7 (on top of a perfectly fresh 10.6), and command-backtick does nothing at all.

Did this feature go away?

Comment: (I know the answer, but it was tricky to find, so I was going to file my own question-and-answer, but apparently I need to wait 8 hours for that.)

Comment: Isn't this the default? I've upgraded machines to Lion and used new Macs with Lion and all have had this turned on.

Comment: That character is not a tilde. This is a tilde: ~.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature is still present (I'm using 10.7.3 and it works for me).

Go to *System Preferences > Keyboard* and check the keyboard shortcuts. In the list of 'Keyboard & Text Input' shortcuts you should see 'Move focus to next window'
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Make sure it is checked, and it should work.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I had found.  From a fresh install of 10.6.3 from a retail DVD onto a blank disk, upgraded immediately to 10.7.3 from the Mac App Store, it had a default of command-F1.  It's doubly strange, since typing command-F1 didn't even work for that, even though both the command and F1 keys work fine in other contexts!

Answer (score 3):

You might also be interested in [Hyperswitch.](http://bahoom.com/hyperswitch)

Along with <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>, hyperswitch allows <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd> to switch between windows of the same app. I find it much more useful than <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>~ (tilde)</kbd> since <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>~ (tilde)</kbd> only iterates through all windows, rather than just toggling between two.